# Java class visible only to current file

Tags: java

Is it possible in Java to define a outer class (i.e. the top level) such that it is only visible to this file? I'd like to have something like static keyword in c++ for restricting visibility in file scope.

If not, why is that and what is the workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the use of having outerclass visible to only that file? I am not that much familiar with c++.

Comment: I would like to know how to restrict also a Java class to another specific package or java class, if possible.

Comment: @thinksteep: an example use is to be able to instantiate instances of that class only for classes defined in this file.

Comment: @SHiRKiT: those are much more demanding than my question. My question is more natural given c++ can do that.

Answer (score 3):

No, what you're asking for is not possible. You can hide classes by making them private static inner classes, or you can put make them top-level, package-protected (default) classes and putting the small group of involved classes into their own package.

Comment: +1 but they don't have to be *static* private inner classes, right, just private inner (and optionally static)?

Comment: No, they don't *have* to be static, but static ones are only minimally different from top-level classes, which is what he was shooting for.

Comment: @maerics making inner classes non-static binds them to the instance of the outer class. This can be extremely useful, but many users do actually want private classes and simply forget (or don't know about) the static keyword. I think some of the static code analysers actually warn you against creating non-static inner classes if they don't use members of the outer class. Always create static inner classes by default.

Comment: @owlstead: yes, thanks for the information, I'm aware of the difference between static and non-static inner classes, just wanted to point out that static is not strictly required to achieve the effect that OP is seeking, although they are generally more useful than their non-static counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

> If not, why is that ...

The only way to get the real answer to a language design issue like that is to ask the language designers.

However the following reasons probably cover it.

- A programming language that tries to support too many things will get too complicated to specify and implement, and to complex for normal programmers to understand.  The former leads to language anomalies and compiler bugs, and the latter leads to bugs in applications.
- The Java language designers thought that 4 levels of access / visibility were sufficient; `public`, `protected`, package private and `private`.
- The Java language designers designed for situations where source code was not organised / stored in discrete files.  It turns out that (nearly) everyone still uses discrete files to represent source code ... but they weren't to know that (20 odd years ago).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are really trying to do, but, to elaborate on @Ernest, you could make a package access class, make it's constructor private for thoroughness, and nothing more in that class.  Then, have a private static inner class with the "real" stuff.  e.g.

```
class Foo {  // "package" access

   private Foo() {}

   private static class Bar {
      // real stuff here...
   }
}
```

p.s. upvotes for this should probably go to Ernest instead, I just elaborated on his idea.